# Is there any option to insert datetime automatically while indexing in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two fields `created_datetime` and `updated_datetime`. I want those to get updated automatically by `elasticsearch` while indexing or udpating. Is there any in-built option by which I can do it?.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html